# Validate phone numbers array in laravel v4.2

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently working on a project in Laravel v4.2, and I have an array of contact numbers as follows:

```
$numbers = array(+156258544,+9661234667,+96592514525,...);
```

Now, I need to validate this array of numbers to determine which contact numbers are valid and which ones are not. I'm wondering if there are any free or paid APIs similar to Twilio that allow for validating an array of numbers instead of just a single contact number.

Alternatively, I'm open to any other methods or approaches that might be useful for tackling this issue.

Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/123681/6384636) which shows a method used for validation. This is a simple method you can use to validate phone numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Loop it through `foreach` and use [Laravel Phone](https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-Phone) library to validate those.

This allows to

1. Validate Number
2. Format Number

Answer (score 0):

In first step, you have to check if this phone number format is really correct. Then, you can check this [link](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/03/how-to-validate-phone-numbers-in-php-with-the-twilio-lookup-api.html) for phone numbers validation.

Comment: @Moslem Cherif link verify one number but I want to validate the array of number in single URL hit.

Comment: @RizwanSaleem you can make a loop for the array.

Comment: @MoslemCherif if I use loop then response time will increase because I have an more than 300+ contacts in my contact list.